# SSJS QueryDefinition fails to create a Query Activity

Tags: ssjs, query-definition

I have the following SSJS code to create a Query Definition but it fails. I cannot seem to find why? Am I missing something here?

I have manually created and execute a Query; It worked but it fails if I use SSJS.

```
    <script runat="server">

    Platform.Load("core", "1.1");

    var queryDefinition = {
        Name : "New Records Query",
        CustomerKey : "newRecordsQuery",
        TargetUpdateType : "Update",
        TargetType : "DE",
        Target : {
            Name : "New Records DE",
            CustomerKey : "newRecordsDE"
        },
        QueryText : "SELECT cp.mdmId, cp.FIRST_NAME, cp.LAST_NAME FROM [CRM_Profiles] cp"
    };
    var statusQueryActivity = QueryDefinition.Add(queryDefinition);

    var outDE = DataExtension.Init("Error-Log"); // just to see the result

    outDE.Rows.Add({ message : statusQueryActivity, log : "Log Message", time : Now() });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you received any error?

Comment: Just Error nothing more

Comment: Try wrapping it in a try/catch to output more error info. Also, have you tried it without the DE stuff below it? does that still error? Have you made sure that the query does not already exist (name/custkey) in the account? (that will cause it to error as this is 'add' only.)

Comment: @Gortonington You are absolutely right on already exists but I cannot seem to find the Query Definition in the Query section. Do you know, where does the query definition get stored?

Comment: It usually defaults to the top level folder when created this way

Comment: I cannot seem to find the Query Definition in the Query Activity section. I have checked top-level folder as well sub-folders.

Comment: Try running `var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("newRecordsQuery");  
var status = qd.Remove();` inside a script activity or CloudPage to remove it. You can then verify if its going to the correct spot on the new creation, rather than searching for it.